# Rails 4 - setting associated foreign key value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, hidden-field

I have a model called project and another called invite.

The associations are:

Project

```
has_many :invites
```

Invite

```
belongs_to :project
```

I want to allow users who create projects to send invites to other users to join them in working on the project.

I have a form to create invites as follows:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@invite, :url => invites_path) do |f| %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :recipient_id, :value => get_recipient_id %>
            <%#= f.hidden_field :project_id, :value => current_user.profile.project_id %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :project_id, :value => @invite.project_id %>
            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.email_field :email %>
            <!-- This field should use :date_picker- but it isnt working -->
            <%= f.input :expiry, :as => :date, :label => "When do you need a response to this invitation?"  %>
            <%#= f.input :expiry, :as => :date_picker, :label => "When do you need a response to this invitation?"  %>


            <%= f.submit 'Send', :class=>"formsubmit" %>
            <% end %>
```

In the above form, I'm trying to set the project_id value.

In the invites controller, I have:

```
class InvitesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :get_project

    def index
        @invites = @project.invites
    end

    def new
      # @invite = Invite.new
      @invite = @project.invites.build
    end

    def create
      @invite = Invite.new(invite_params)
      @invite.sender_id = current_user.profile.id
      # @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])

      if @invite.save
           #send existing user email invitation to join project team
           InviteMailer.existing_user_invite(@invite).deliver_later 
           format.html { redirect_to @project }

           @invite.recipient.project.push(@invite.project)
        else
            @invite.recipient.project.push(@invite.project)
             InviteMailer.new_user_invite(@invite, new_user_registration_path(:invite_token => @invite.token)).deliver
        end

         # oh no, creating an new invitation failed

    end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_invite
      @invite = Invite.find(params[:id])
    end

    def get_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def invite_params
      params[:invite].permit(:email, :project_id, :recipient_id)
    end   
end
```

I thought the get_project before action would get the project. Instead, I get an error that says:

```
undefined method `project_id' for #<Profile:0x007fa179509b60>
Did you mean?  project_ids
               project_ids=
               projects
               object_id
```

The error message points to the hidden field in my form for project_id.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the statement `current_user.profile.project_id` in one of the hidden form fields.

(The error message points to this code but I don't know why you have commented that line in the post)

The error clearly says that a `profile` does not have a `project_id` and a user can have many projects. If you want to access the `project_id`, you can do something like this.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :project_id, value: @project.id %>
```

`@project` is accessible from the controller through the `get_project` method.

Comment: No - I think the error message points to this line, which is not commented:  <%= f.hidden_field :project_id, :value => @invite.project_id %>

Comment: The error message doesnt say anything about profile. It is talking about an error with project_id.

Comment: `undefined method `project_id' for #<Profile:0x007fa179509b60>` the error says that `profile` instance doesn't have a `project_id` method.

Comment: ah - i see. Thanks Arun. I didn't construe that meaning from the message.